# How to connect firebase if I have multiple modules in my android native app

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on my Final year project, which is an android native app, using Kotlin. my question is how to connect firebase with all modules do I need to copy the JSON file in every module as well as add all the required dependencies in every module i.e. auth module, resources module, etc. I am confused about this I think this would be really hard to maintain.

Please give me some best suggestions on how to handle multi-module project effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add dependency in each and every module, let's just keep all the firebase related handling in separate `firebase` module and add that module in main `app` module. From `app` module you can simply call the implementation in `firebase` module and make it work.

PS: please make sure the project you are gonna develop ***has to be*** multi-module. Not every app needs to develop on multi-module approach IMO.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. if I add another module named FIREBASE or BACKEND, then when creating firebase project on 'console.firebase.google.com' they want an android package name which will be 'com.myapp.project' in my case I have multiple modules and they are (android library module type) i.e. auth module, product module, purchase control module, resource module, and there is one main app module which is executable or runnable in the device. so of which module package should I provide I am confused whether the new module that I created the firebase package name or the main app mod.

Comment: Main app module - because that's an android application module which is gonna communicate with firebase project - not library module.

Comment: but the activities and code runs  in  authentication module,  and I am trying to do  that its not working

Comment: its something like this-> when my app launches the main activity starts a  new intent which start the activity of authentication module and there is  the login fragment which execute the continue with google good but its not working its going  to  thefailed task. its not going  to task.isSuccessful

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thankyou Malik it just worked!

Comment: can I  ask you something related does my this approach of multi-module is correct? I separated every module and in every module, there is the layouts activities and the related business logic are there with it and all these modules depend upon resource module which has icons, colors, etc. as well as the main app module is responsible for the navigation of one module activity to another module or deciding when to start which activity. I will really appreciate your answer in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

As you are already having a multi module Android app, so you definitely must be having a base/core module on which all the other modules must be depending on.

There are 2 things you can do

1. Add a common wrapper class where are firebase related code is present into your base module and then access the same across different modules.
2. Use *api* instead of *implementation* in your build.gradle file while adding firebase dependancy. This way you will get access to Firebase across all the modules which depend on your base/common module.